# VF2 Subgraph Isomorphism

Tags: java, graph

I want to solve the subgraph isomorphism problem. I have one large graph. Nodes and edges has repeating labels and graph also has loops in it. I want to identify the all occurrences of subgraph in the large graph.

Please suggest me any pseudo code in Java.

Is VF2 can resolve this problem, if yes then please mention any link from where I can understand the basic functionality of the VF2 algorithm

Please suggest me ant link from where I can understand the basic functionality of the VF2 algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Try the implementation used by the S-Space project.

It contains a good implementation of VF2.

- https://github.com/fozziethebeat/S-Space

The VF2 algorithm is here:

- https://github.com/fozziethebeat/S-Space/tree/master/src/main/java/edu/ucla/sspace/graph/isomorphism

Comment: S-Space doesn't implement methods to discover subgraph isomorphism in graphs. https://github.com/fozziethebeat/S-Space/issues/62

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [from-scratch Java implementation of VF2](http://depth-first.com/articles/2008/11/17/substructure-search-from-scratch-in-java-part-1-the-atom-mapping-problem/) for cheminformatics, which you can [download from GitHub](http://github.com/metamolecular/mx). I've also written a [high-level overview of VF2](http://depth-first.com/articles/2008/11/13/one-of-these-things-is-not-like-the-other/).