# VF2 (or other) graph isomorphism implementation in Java

Tags: java, graph, graph-algorithm, isomorphism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VF2 Subgraph Isomorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600787/vf2-subgraph-isomorphism)

I want to implement graph isomorphism algorithm in Java but I face a lot of problems due to small programming experience (maybe logic as well). After some research I found that three heuristic algorithms are available: Ullman, Nauty and VF2. VF2 is considered fastest and simplest to implement as I was told by some PhD student. I read the paper devoting to VF2 but unfortunately don't understand how it works (in code) and what to do with feasibility rules.
A lot of guys here refer to C++ code implementation, but unfortunately, the link doesn't open.
Furthermore, one user (Rich Apodaca) suggested to look at his implementation (MX) of VF2 for chemists but didn't point out which files, just big project...
Please help me to implement isomorphism algorithm in java (better VF2 because of speed) and point out to working code (not the whole project, it is hard for me to understand the structure) in Java or C++ (which I don't know but at least I can try).
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the implementation used by the S-Space project.

It contains a good implementation of VF2.

- https://github.com/fozziethebeat/S-Space

The VF2 algorithm is here:

- https://github.com/fozziethebeat/S-Space/tree/master/src/main/java/edu/ucla/sspace/graph/isomorphism

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I can go with this.

Comment: I'm using it and so far it seems really good and fast